# ¿Cómo evitar respuesta correcta, cuando la información enviada es falsa Ajax | PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

El siguiente código me permite ingresar registros nuevos cuando no existe un `id` que actualizar, hasta ahí va funcionando bien, pero intentando actualizar un registro que no existe, por ejemplo el `id` `20` cuando en mi tabla de datos solo tengo 5 registros que van de manera consecutiva desde el `id` `1` hasta el `id` `5`.

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['ajaxData'])) {
        $id = $_POST["item_id"];
        $nombre_cliente = $_POST["nombre_cliente"];

        if (empty($_POST['nombre_cliente'])){
            echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["nombre_cliente" =>"Por favor, ingresé el nombre del cliente para continuar."]]);
            exit;
        }
        
        if($id != '') {
            $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE cliente
                                    SET
                                        nombre_cliente = ?
                                    WHERE id_cliente = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("si",
                                $nombre_cliente,
                                $id
                            );
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                echo json_encode(['status'=> true, 'message'=>"<strong>Los datos se actualizaron correctamente.</strong>"]);
                exit;
            } else {
                echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"<strong>Lo sentimos, pero no podemos procesar su solicitud. Inténtalo más tarde.</strong>"]);
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            $stmtAdd = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente (nombre_cliente) VALUES (?)");
            $stmtAdd->bind_param("s",$nombre_cliente);
            if ($stmtAdd->execute()) {
                echo json_encode(['status'=> true, 'message'=>"<strong>Nuevo cliente registrado correctamente.</strong>"]);
                exit;
            } else {
                echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"<strong>Lo sentimos, pero no podemos procesar su solicitud. Inténtalo más tarde.</strong>"]);
                exit;       
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

Entonces cuando envió la actualización de dicho `id 20` que no existe, ajax, me emite un comunicado de que se actualizaron los datos correctamente, cuando esto no debe pasar, porque son datos que no existen, debería emitirme el mensaje `false` y, no el `true`.

Este es mi código ajax:

```
$(function() {
    var frm = $('#ajaxData');
    frm.submit(function(e){
        //$('.error', '#resetform').remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = frm.serialize();
        formData += '&' + $('#submit_data').attr('name') + '=' + $('#submit_data').attr('value');
        
        var url = "update_cliente.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: url,
            data: formData,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            let res = JSON.parse(data);
            // si es true el estado
            if(res.status){
                $('.success').fadeIn();
                $('.success').html(res.message).delay(8000).fadeOut(8000);
                $(frm)[0].reset();
                $(frm).hide();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.href = 'cliente.php';
                },9000);
            } else {
                for (let name in res.message) {
                    $('.error').remove();
                    let msg = '<span class="error">' + res.message[name] + '</span>';
                    $(msg).insertAfter($('[name=' + name + ']', '#ajaxData'));
                    $('.error').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut(5000);
                }
            }
        })
        .fail(function() {
            $('.warning').fadeIn();
            $('.warning').html(textStatus).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
        })
    });
});
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?, ¿es error de Ajax o del planteamiento del código de PHP?

Comment: El problema es que esto solo no sirve para saber si ocurrió alguna actualización: `if ($stmt->execute()) {`  debes verificar también las **filas afectadas** con [`affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php), por ejemplo: **`if ($stmt->execute() && $stmt->affected_rows>0) {`** Lo mismo ocurre con los INSERT. Solamente cuando `affected_rows` sea mayor que `0` habrá ocurrido el UPDATE, el INSERT o un DELETE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que esto solo no sirve para saber si ocurrió alguna actualización:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) { // ...
```

El método `execute()` devolve  `true` cuando no hay error al ejecutar una consulta. Pero una consulta con un `WHERE` cuyo criterio no se cumple no es una consulta errónea, es simplemente una consulta que no devuelve nada o no hace nada o no cambia nada realmente.

Es por eso que debes verificar también las **filas afectadas** con [`affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php).

Lo mismo ocurre con los `INSERT` y con los `DELETE`. Solamente cuando `affected_rows` sea mayor que `0` habrá ocurrido **realmente** el `UPDATE`, el `INSERT` o un eventual `DELETE`.

Para aplicar lo que hemos dicho, puedes modificar tus bloques de `UPDATE` e `INSERT` de este modo:

En el `UPDATE`:

```
        if ($stmt->execute() && $stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            echo json_encode(['status'=> true, 'message'=>"<strong>Los datos se actualizaron correctamente.</strong>"]);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"<strong>Lo sentimos, pero no podemos procesar su solicitud. Inténtalo más tarde.</strong>"]);
            exit;
        }
```

Y en el `INSERT`:

```
        if ($stmtAdd->execute() && $stmtAdd->affected_rows > 0) {
            echo json_encode(['status'=> true, 'message'=>"<strong>Nuevo cliente registrado correctamente.</strong>"]);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"<strong>Lo sentimos, pero no podemos procesar su solicitud. Inténtalo más tarde.</strong>"]);
            exit;       
        }
```

Cabe decir que un `UPDATE` que estuviera basado en los mismos datos que ya existen también devolvería `0` en `affected_rows`. Por ejemplo, si el nombre actual es `Pedro` y le mandas a que lo actualice a `Pedro` la consulta se intenta, pero te devuelve `0` filas afectadas. El SGBD no es tonto, imagino que de algún modo verifica que el dato que va a setear como nuevo sea distinto al que ya existe antes de confirmar el UPDATE. Claro está que si hay otra(s) columna(s) a actualizar, con algún valor distinto a los que existen, aunque `Pedro` sea igual, ocurrirá el UPDATE porque hay algo diferente en esa(s) otra(s) columna(s).

De todos modos, quizá convendría evitar desde el cliente que se envíen consultas inútiles al servidor, como mandar a actualizar un registro que no existe. Pero ese es otro asunto...

Comment: Funciona bien, pero no me emite los mensajes de errores, por ejemplo el de por favor, ingresé el nombre del cliente, acaso esas advertencia deben ir dentro de `if ($stmtAdd->execute() && $stmtAdd->affected_rows > 0) {` por otra parte ya mencionado esa misma línea que me has recomendado, solo ejecuta el mensaje de que los datos han sido actualizado en caso de error no muestra el mensaje de `else` mensaje de falso.

Comment: @Valentina no entendí tu comentario. El mensaje que dice que ingrese el nombre del cliente no tiene nada que ver con lo planteado en mi respuesta. Ese mensaje evalúa el POST y se emite si la condición que evalúas en esa parte se cumple. Aunque llama la atención que pongas el mensaje dentro de un sub-array ¿? Tampoco entiendo lo que dices sobre *en caso de error*. Con el código como está ahora, si el execute es exitoso y hay una o más filas afectadas te mostrará el mensaje de éxito, de lo contrario mostrará el de error. ¿No era eso lo que querías?

Comment: Gracias ya solucione el problema.